# Прокрутка внутри блока с помощью jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью jQuery можно "оживить" данную форму, а именно работала вертикальная прокрутка контента внутри блока и, соответственно, работал ползунок рядом.

Вот заготовка формы:

```
<div style="width: 200px; margin: 10px; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #000;">
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <div class="scrollbar-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wall">
        <div id="scroller">
            <p>Scroll Me!</p>
            <p>Hello World</p>
            <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Полностью](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jpennq/).

Comment: Для скролла с помощью колёсика мыши внутри блока можно повесить обработчик события `mousewheel` на `#scroller`. Для скролла с помощью полосы прокрутки можно повесить обработчики событий `mousedown`, `mousemove` и `mouseup` на `.scrollbar`. А уже внутри обработчиков двигать `#scroller`.

Comment: @Regent а в самом обработчике как потом перемещать сам контент внутри блока? вот пока добавил [обработчик](http://jsfiddle.net/wao138/r6jpennq/2/).

Comment: Идея можно такую использовать: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jpennq/3/). Нужно ставить ограничения на мин. и макс. значения, нужно полосу прокрутки двигать на пропорциональное кол-во пикселей и т.д., но работать будет.

Comment: @Regent вот постарался добавить ограничения, так? А вот ползунок своей жизнью живет:D
[вот](http://jsfiddle.net/wao138/r6jpennq/4/)

Comment: Я кое-где просчитался (с коэффициентом сдвига и с минимальным допустимым `marginTop`), но что-то вроде этого: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jpennq/5/).

Comment: @Regent спасибо, а вот как отображение последней строки полным сделать? а то на половину показывает его? `padding` в `#scroller` поставить? [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/wao138/r6jpennq/7/).

Comment: На здоровье. А где и какая "последняя строка" не полностью отображается? Я в этой версии кода вполне хорошо вижу _Hello World20_

Comment: @Regent я просто уже добавил `padding` в `#scroller`, вот если его убрать, то _Hello World20_ видно не будет

Comment: По-моему, дело в том, что последний необходимый шаг скролла не разрешается. [Новая версия](http://jsfiddle.net/r6jpennq/8/) без `padding` и с изменённым значением `minMargin`.

Comment: @Regent спасибо!